# priority queue data structure

Tags: data-structures, priority-queue

Suppose that I have a priority queue which removes elements in increasing order, and stored in this queue are the elements `1, 1, 3, 0, 1`. The increasing order is `0` then `1` then `3`, but there are three element `1`s.

When I call `remove` it will first remove the `0`, but if I call `remove` again will it remove all three `1`s at the same time, or will I need to call `remove` three separate times to remove all of the `1` elements.

Does a call to `remove` on such a priority queue remove all elements of the same minimum value or will only one element be removed with each call?

Comment: Not a real question unless you say what implementation you're using.

Comment: "An unsorted array"? In that case, you're implementing the data type yourself and so you can decide what you want to do...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a priority queue usually the remove operation removes a single record containing the maximum value. So in your case it would be the second option. The order of removal is not guaranteed. Any key with the "maximum" value would be removed. Also, unsorted array is a bad data structure of implement a priority queue. You would typically use a heap data structure to get O(log(n)) guarantees on insertion and removal.

Answer (score 0):

typical heap implementation would always reheap the tree therefore it would remove 0, 1, 1, 1 and then 3 as 1 would get push to the root during reheapification..

am i wrong?

edit: your case is a min-heap